# How to sort filenames by the numerical order of their content (UNIX)?

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, ubuntu, cat

I am trying to write a script that will output a list of file names (without the extension) organized by the numerical order of the data inside the files. The content of every file looks something like this (one line, two columns):

```
2004kg 1.3m
```

I just started coding in the UNIX environment this week and have a very limited knowledge of commands and arguments, so I have only been able to have my script output the content of the files in numerical order. I have coded the following to display the contents of all my .dat files sorted by the numerical order of the first column of their contents.

```
cat *.dat | sort -n -k1
```

How would I go about having my output be the names of the .dat files, but still keep them sorted by the contents?

Comment: This question may belong on superuser instead. Shell commands are not generally regarded as programming unless its done as part of program.

Comment: If you want to sort by the `kg` number, then you can do something like `(for i in *; do echo "$(<"$i") $i"; done) | sort -n | awk '{print $3}'` You are basically just loading the contents along with the filename onto a line and then sorting the results by number before `kg` and then printing the filenames alone. (p.s. if you ever find yourself doing `cat X | something`, that is probably an unnecessary use of cat (a UUOC))

Comment: why not renamed you files to match the sortable value?You could prepend that value to the existing name i.e. `2004kg_file1.dat` ? It's unclear why you would need to do this, but that is one solution. This eliminates debugging problems any further along in your processing chain, as you won't have to go back and inspect the file to see why is is appearing where it is in you list of files. Good luck.